# NuGet.Config does not contain the expected root element: 'configuration'

Tags: nuget

We recently switched from `nuget.exe` **3.3** to **5.5** and because of the switch we are receiving the following error:

`NuGet.Config does not contain the expected root element: 'configuration'.`

Running the following command via nuget.exe

```
nuget.exe restore  ..\path\solutionfolder\solution.sln -ConfigFile ..\path\solutionfolder\projectfolder\packages.config
```

Something we are doing is not correct.

`Packages.config` looks as follows:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
      <package id="Elasticsearch.Net" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
    </packages>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue turned out to be quite simple, we should **not** have had the ConfigFile command line entry present.

```
nuget.exe restore  ..\path\solutionfolder\solution.sln
```

Comment: Good catch, and almost impossible to debug.